# Why does my CleanScreen function not work?

Tags: python, console, console-application

This is my current project (Python 3.8). Your supposed to be able to draw things on your screen. This is not my full version. Its just for explanation purposes. The problem is that if you run `run.py` it doesn't clear the screen. Shouldn't the new Frame just push the old one out of frame? Do you know what my problem is?

`main.py`:

```
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime
import logging
import ctypes




class ConsoleGameEngine:
    def __init__(self, windowWidth, windowHeight):
        logging.basicConfig(filename=f'debug\{datetime.now().strftime("%H-%M-%S")}-main.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
        
        
        self.screenWidth = windowWidth
        self.screenHeight = windowHeight

        self.var = ""
        self.pixel = u"\u2591"#u"\u25A1"
        self.lightShade = u"\u2591"
        self.mediumShade = u"\u2592"
        self.darkShade = u"\u2593"
        
        os.system(f'mode con: cols={self.windowWidth} lines={self.windowHeight}')

        """
        SCREEN ACCESS:
        self.screen[y][x]
        """
        self.clearScreenVar = [[" " for w in range(self.screenWidth)] for h in range(self.screenHeight)]
        self.screen = self.clearScreenVar

    
    def clearScreen(self):

        """
        for y in range(self.windowHeight):
            for x in range(self.windowHeight):
                self.screen[y][x] = " "
        """
        self.screen = self.clearScreenVar
            
    
    
    def drawPixel(self,x,y,shade=u"\u2591"):
        try:
            self.screen[y][x] = shade
        except Exception as e:
            logging.warning(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S~")+str(e)+f"~Failed drawing pixel at x: {x} and/or y: {y}")
    
          
    def sleep(self, t = 1):
        time.sleep(t)
        
    def printScreen(self):
        print("".join(["".join(x) for x in self.screen]))
```

`run.py`:

```
from main import ConsoleGameEngine

win = ConsoleGameEngine(120, 40)
x = 0
while True:
    win.drawPixel(x,20)
    win.printScreen()
    win.sleep(0.1)
    win.clearScreen()
    x += 1
```

Comment: `self.screen = self.clearScreenVar` does not copy the list data but makes `self.screen` point to the same data as `self.clearScreenVar`. So when you modify `self.screen` in `drawPixel` you are also modifying `self.clearScreenVar`

Comment: Cool, thanks. Is there a way to preclaculate the empty screen or do i just have to calculate every screen wipe?